# How to copy all the data from usb to specific location on OS X using terminal

Tags: macos, unix

I need a command which can copy all the data from pen drive to specific location on "OS X" using terminal.
And also how to recognize pen drive on OS X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On OS X all usb devices are mounted under /Volumes, so

```
cp -R /Volumes/pendrive ~/somewhereinyourhome
```

As to recognise a pendrive: type (in xterm) 'df' before plugging it in, type it again afterwards. Whatever new volume shows up thats your pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

To list all of the hard drives on your system, try this command in the OS X terminal application:

```
diskutil list
```

Comment: Properly editing your answer with mark down syntax will help increase it's quality. You can surround your code with back ticks `\``

Answer (score 1):

To see the name of your USB storage device you can either look at the Desktop, or list the drives in your Volumes directory:

```
ls -d /Volumes/*
```

You can then copy the files to a local directory:

```
cp -a /Volumes/DEVICENAME/* ~/LOCALPATH
```

For me the drive is usually called "NO NAME", which requires a backslash to escape the space character:

```
cp -a /Volumes/NO\ NAME/* ~/LOCALPATH
```